# MySQL - json column

Tags: mysql, json

I want to create a column where I need to save a JSON OBJECT.

> But mysql return me:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'json null' at line 2

when I try to do this:

```
alter table meeting
    add attendee json null;
```

Comment: check your mysql version please

Comment: @Firewizz JSON is, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: Didn't knew that, learned something new today lol, tnx. (removed old comment due to wrong information)